# iOS 11.x system colors

Tags: ios, swift, colors, controls

I've read a lot of posts on how to customize Views colors, but nothing about retrieving system colors for standard controls like the Navigation Bar, Status Bar and Tab Bar in iOS 11.x or previous. The class UIColor has 3 system colors but they are pretty useless. Calling UINavigationBar.appearance(), for example, is of little help because it'll probably return the "clear" color for the default light color scheme, in case nothing has been defined in the application plist. So why doesn't Apple supply a way to programmatically get the system colors as others do (for Windows and Android) ? Has anybody any idea where to find them ? Tx in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for these colors? https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/visual-design/color/

Comment: The system colors yes, but programmatically, by name, not by their RGB values, in order to have the correct color every time they are changed by Apple

Answer (score 14):

**Update for 2019**

`UIColor` now provides static properties to get the system colors.

Example:

```
UIColor.systemBlue
```

For a full list of system colors, check out the "Standard Colors" page in the UIKit documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/standard_colors

---

**Old Answer**

iOS does not provide a way to access these colors programmatically.

Instead, it's simple enough to add these colors to your own project. If the colors change in a future iOS version (and you want to use those new colors instead), you will need to update your app.

In most cases, this is not an issue since apps define their own colors for branding purposes.

```
enum SystemColor {

    case red
    case orange
    case yellow
    case green
    case tealBlue
    case blue
    case purple
    case pink

    var uiColor: UIColor {
        switch self {
        case .red:
            return UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 59/255, blue: 48/255, alpha: 1)
        case .orange:
            return UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 149/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1)
        case .yellow:
            return UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 204/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1)
        case .green:
            return UIColor(red: 76/255, green: 217/255, blue: 100/255, alpha: 1)
        case .tealBlue:
            return UIColor(red: 90/255, green: 200/255, blue: 250/255, alpha: 1)
        case .blue:
            return UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 122/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)
        case .purple:
            return UIColor(red: 88/255, green: 86/255, blue: 214/255, alpha: 1)
        case .pink:
            return UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 45/255, blue: 85/255, alpha: 1)
        }
    }

}
```

Sample usage:

```
myView.backgroundColor = SystemColor.blue.uiColor
```

If you prefer, these colors could also be defined as an extension on `UIColor` like so:

```
extension UIColor {
    static let systemBlue = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 122/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)
    // etc
}
```

and the usage would look like this:

```
UIColor.systemBlue
```

---

[image: iOS system colors from the hig]

[Colors in the Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/visual-design/color/)

Comment: Thank you @nathan I knew several ways to get that result. My app doesn't have custom colors. It depends on the system colors by design. So, your solution doesn't satisfy my needs. Thank you anyway for your time

Comment: @Sergiob There is no solution that can satisfy your needs that I am aware of. This is the best you can do with the current limitations of the iOS APIs.

Comment: Downvoted because with the new version of Xcode you can access system colors. See Roman Podymov's post.

Comment: It says specifically in the interface guidelines not to do this, because the color values can change in different scenarios, e.g. due to dark appearance and accessibility settings.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Updated the answer to include the new API in UIKit.

Answer (score 3):

Since Xcode 11.0 you can use `UIColor.systemRed`, `UIColor.systemGreen`, `UIColor.systemBlue` and other `UIColor.system*` properties to solve the issue you described.