# How to access the system colors programmatically in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor

I'm trying to programmatically set the background color of an UIButton to the color `UIColor.systemBlue`, which I assume should be accessible according to the docs of [UIColor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/standard_colors/) and the [color guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/color/#system-colors). However, I can only access the regular colors such as `.blue` and `.red`. In the interface builder I can select `systemBlue` but not programmatically.

I'm using Xcode 10.3 and building for iOS 12.4.

**EDIT**:
I've seen the question [iOS 11.x system colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47995595/ios-11-x-system-colors), but it doesn't make sense. In the color guidelines it's clearly stated that the system color values shouldn't be hard-coded, but to use the API instead. And in the UIColor docs the system colors seem to be accessible as public class vars of UIColor.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47996017/4757272

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS 11.x system colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47995595/ios-11-x-system-colors)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These system colors are only available when using the iOS 13 SDK, meaning you must use Xcode 11, not Xcode 10.3.

Comment: I see. Weird that they are accessible in the interface builder in Xcode 10 though. Too bad this fact isn't stated in the docs anywhere.

Comment: Yeah that's weird that you're seeing them in Interface Builder in Xcode 10, as I can't seem to find anything that says "systemBlue" or "System Blue" for stuff like background color or tint color. And yeah, Apple's docs could use some work. They don't really say which version of the iOS SDK a particular thing became available in – they just say which version of iOS it can _run_ on (in the case of `systemBlue`, all the way down to iOS 7 it seems, meaning it must have been a private API until Xcode 11).

Comment: You can choose them in IB from `Background -> Custom -> Color Palettes` and then _Developer_ from the drop-down menu.